# Where can I find the latest Swagger definition of the DocuSign eSignature REST API?

Tags: c#, .net, docusignapi

I'm trying to use this tool generator.swagger.io to create my own SDK for the DocuSign eSignature REST API instead of the one provided on GitHub to make sure my SDK version is always up to date with DocuSign development.

My question is: Is this Swagger definition https://raw.githubusercontent.com/docusign/eSign-OpenAPI-Specification/master/esignature.rest.swagger.json always be the latest one which align with all DocuSign new features?

When I use that Swagger definition to generate SDK I noticed in the ApiClient.cs class there's no method called "ConfigureJwtAuthorizationFlow()" whereas in the one in GitHub that method exists, so not quite sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ConfigureJwtAuthorizationFlow was added to the SDK to enable developers to get an access token via a JWT OAuth flow.

The JWT OAuth flow is part of the [DocuSign OAuth implementation](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication), per se.

So it isn't in the DocuSign eSignature REST API Swagger file. Someday DocuSign will have a Swagger file for its OAuth protocol but we're not there yet.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for clarifying :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the proper  version of API.

Comment: I have always been using the latest version v2 of the rest api. What I wasn't sure about is the Swagger Definition provided above, is it gonna be the latest of the api as well? If not, where can I find the latest Swagger Definition?